# Disable all div contents using jquery including anchor, paragraph tags?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i need a little help in html css, i want to disable all contents in a div having class "main-wrapper" after user clicks on a logout button through a jquery function, i tried in 2 ways, but in vain!
here is my jquery function,

```
function loadLogoutBox() {
    $('#logout_box').fadeIn("slow");
    $(".main-wrapper").css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "0.3"  
    });
    $(".main-wrapper").disable();
    $(".top-menu").attr('disabled', true);

}
```

any help please!

Comment: `.contents()` or `.contains()`

Comment: post some codes of ur html.

Comment: In addition to posting the relevant markup, can you define more specifically what you mean by "disable all contents"?

Comment: all my divs are in "main-wrapper class", i dont want to hide it, but i set its opacity :0.3, so a popup appears fine, opacity works fine, but i can still contact behind the popup box, all i want is that, when user just has been loggedout, then he can see the page, but with no more interactions!

Comment: Add a overlay inside the `.main-wrapper` with `absolute` position and desired `opacity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a div that takes up 100% width and height with a transparent background and have it appear above the main wrapper and below the logout box.

HTML:

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1; /* make sure logout_box has a z-index of 2 */
  background-color: none;
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function loadLogoutBox() {
    $("#cover").css("display", "block");
    $('#logout_box').fadeIn("slow");
    $(".main-wrapper").css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "0.3"  
    });
}
```

With this method, you will obviously also have to add some jQuery to take away the cover once the user returns to the main screen.

This can be done simply by:

```
$("#cover").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Tabbed selection of elements?

Answer (score 2):

The `disabled` attribute only applies to as subset of `form` elements (`input`, `button`, `select` and `texarea` are the only I can think of right off the bat)

```
$('.main-wrapper').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Also you can put an overlay `div` over your wrapper to prevent selection and anchor tag usage. Add a `div` to your HTML and then add this to your JS and CSS:

#### JavaScript

```
var mainWrapper = $('.main-wrapper')

mainWrapper.find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
var mainWrapperPos = mainWrapper.position();
var mainWrapperHeight = mainWrapper.height();
var mainWrapperWidth = mainWrapper.width();

$('#cover').css({
    'opacity':0.3,
    'top': mainWrapperPos.top,
    'left': mainWrapperPos.left,
    'height': mainWrapperHeight,
    'width': $('.main-wrapper').width()
});
```

#### CSS

```
#cover {
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Note:** You should do both the iteration of disabled and the overlay to prevent tabbed selection. Also with `<a>` anchor elements you could set the `href` to `#` to prevent tabbed usage also.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/LuqFu/5/)

Comment: Using `,` to separate `textarea`, `button`, and `select` will make those select *all* of those elements, not just the ones inside of `.main-wrapper`. You're going to need `.main-wrapper` in front of all of them, or use the optional context argument (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)).

Comment: @ChristopherW it works fine for the inputs, but what about my anchor tags, i want to disable each and every thing!
is there any other way to do this

Comment: @user2324242 I'm about to update

Comment: @user2324242 Alright it should be good now

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/fvGuq/)**</kbd>

Add a `overlay` layer inside your wrapper, and make it at front of **all** your elements, but at back of your popup. Consider you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">

    Here you have data

    <span class="logout">[LOGOUT]</span>

    <div class="popup">You have successfully logout</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>

</div>
```

And with some css:

```
.main-wrapper {
    background: green;
    padding: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 5000;
    display: none;
}

.popup {
    background: red;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 6000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

And when you click LOGOUT:

```
$(function () {
    $('.logout').on('click', function () {
        $('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
        $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Check the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/fvGuq/).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html, the most likely problem is that $(".main-wrapper") returns a collection which has no disable method. You'll need to enumerate and find the objects which do have a disable function and call that instead.

Edit: There is no jquery disable method. You'll need to either hide elements or disable them with $object.prop('disabled', true);

Answer (score 0):

This code is for disable all input element of a div having class main-wrapper .

```
     $('.main-wrapper :input').attr('disabled', true);
```

same like input element you can disable other element by placing tag name in place of input.

```
      $('.main-wrapper :select').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$(".top-menu").attr('disabled', true);
```

should be, here we assumes `.top-menu` is applied on `input`,`textarea`, etc

```
$(".top-menu").prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$(".top-menu").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right.But i can suggest you a work around ,have a empty div hidden with the same height,width and position of the div $(".main-wrapper") but with z-index more than the $(".main-wrapper") div.Initially have the empty div hidden ,and when user clicks on logout show the empty div,there by the empty div recieves all the click events and your $(".main-wrapper") div looks disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to create an overlay over your content, and behind the popup. And I believe the correct CSS is as follows:

.overlay {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #000;
     opacity: 0.3:
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}

You may or may not have to add a z-index. Then just use some jQuery to fadeIn the element.

However, this DIV cannot be used as a container. It must be a stand alone element.

And excuse me for not formatting, I am on my iPhone.