# Finding spec valid attributes for a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I came across a [question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642919/disable-all-div-contents-using-jquery) where, in part, the user wanted to disable all the form elements within a container upon a triggered event using jQuery.

For part of my answer, I suggested selecting the container and finding the form elements and then iterating over each one with `.each()`.

In whole, the selector was similar to this:

```
$('.container').find('input, textarea, button, select');
```

The `find()` portion was rather long I thought, but these were the only elements I could think of that took the `disabled` attribute according to the HTML specification (if there are more, please feel free to inform me). Now to my question.

Is there anyway to iterate through a group of DOM elements (perhaps returned by jQuery but [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) will work too) and determine if the current element can take an attribute that is valid according to the HTML specification? I.E. I have a group of elements and on one of the iterations I get a `strong` element. `disabled` doesn't do anything for a `strong` element so it skips it and moves on to an `input` element, which `disabled` work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Browsers don't provide an API for determining what elements/attributes are valid. They also provide a lot of error recovery features, so testing by creating an element with attributes and seeing what happens to them isn't reliable.

You would need to compare against a specification.

HTML 4 and XHTML 1.x have DTDs that you could write a parser for.

Comment: Cut and dry. Thanks. Maybe I'll write a plugin.