# CSS disabled property not disabling the buttons

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-ajax

I am disabling the div containing textbox and button controls. While textboxes are getting disabled, buttons are not getting disabled.
Below is the javascript code to disable that I am calling on page load

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_TabContainer1").disabled = true;
```

TabContainer is basically a **AJAX TabContainer** that rendered to div and its ID becomes **MainContent_TabContainer1**

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried setting pointerEvents to none?

Comment: I have a lots of controls and setting pointer-event property for all the controls is not realistic. Also, the scenario is like when user in my application is not logged in, I want to disable the complete page while if logged in things will be in normal state and all the buttons should be clickable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't disable a DIV: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html  You will probably need to loop through the elements it contains.

Comment: Bob is right. I would set a class to the buttons, call getElementsByClassName, and loop through the results, setting each one to disabled

Comment: Ah, this is rude!! Ok, I will try this out. Thanks for quick response guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer of below question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642919/disable-all-div-contents-using-jquery-including-anchor-paragraph-tags)

Just mask a div onto parent div. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

*I would set a class to the buttons, call getElementsByClassName, and loop through the results, setting each one to disabled*

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/794y2760/) to demonstrate this.

HTML:

```
<div id='hold'>
    <button class='btn'>Click Me</button>
    <button class='btn'>Click Me</button>
    <button class='btn'>Click Me</button>
    <div class='btn'>Click Me</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var x=0;x<buttons.length;x++) {
    buttons[x].disabled = true;
    buttons[x].style.pointerEvents = 'none'; //disables div buttons
}
```

Comment: This is not a fool proof solution. I tried it and it leaves some divs that has onclick event(Used as buttons). Best way is to mask it with a div over your document

Comment: Oh, in that case, I would use `ele.style.pointerEvents = 'none'`. But to each his own

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are not using IE to run this project, you can use the below solution :-
- Replacing 'div' with 'fieldset' and disabling the 'fieldset' will disable all input and buttons inside

```
<fieldset id="parent" >
 <button class='btn' onClick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
 <input type="text"/>
</fieldset>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("parent").disabled = true;
}
```

2) To disable each input and button inside the parent div

```
<div id="parent" >
 <button class='btn' onClick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
</div>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
 var myDiv = document.getElementById( "parent" ); 

 var inputArr = myDiv.getElementsByTagName( "input" ); 
 for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) 
 inputArr[i].disabled = true;

 var btnArr = myDiv.getElementsByTagName( "button" ); 
 for (var i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) 
  btnArr[i].disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Note : Just to show the disabling, the function is tied to the button present in the parent div

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript code will complete your task

```
var nod = document.getElementById("MainContent_TabContainer1").getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < nod.length; i++) {
    nod[i].disabled = true;
}
```

If you want to do this job by jquery then you can write the following code

```
$("#MainContent_TabContainer1 *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

Comment: It does not work for div that has onclick attribute and also anchor tags. But thanks for the suggestions. Best way I found to achieve it is mask the parent div with another div